# JMeter J2EE session login

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, jmeter, jsessionid

Folks,

Im new to JMeter and have couple of questions, if anybody can give me some hints, that would be great.

1.)First of all Im trying to simulate a Login on a J2EE machine: I recorded a Login request using the blazemeter Chrome plugin and cleaned up the resource stuff I obviously dont need for a Login simulation, like JSON, JS etc...

At the end my Testplan looks like this:

[test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfKs7.jpg)

So my as you can see my initial Login request passes username and Password and getting a JSESSIONID back, which seems to be provided to the following request successful:

[Response Header Login request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIgga.jpg)

[request Header following request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxjWs.jpg)

However, this doesnt seems to work properly, since my Response data doesnt contain the data Im would expect, instead I see a Java exception stack trace:

[Java error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5gJL.jpg)

So I would strongly assume the logon isnt successful. Since Im the JSESSIONID seems to be passen properly, debuger Output:

[debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebBba.jpg)

reg Extractor for the Cookie value from first Response header:

[reg exp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5TmV.jpg)

resp putting it within the header Manager of the next request:

[header manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv0sO.jpg)

I have currently no clue whats going wrong. I guess Im doing something wrong, if somebody has an idea I would be glad about some Support on this issue.

2.)The second question I have is regarding broken or missing Response files, which are coming back on a replayed request. On the current stand of the Project Im working in, some resources are indeed missing, e.g. a picture should be loaded on my initial Login request. In the generated Response I can see:

[one failed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuJNS.jpg)

My question is: I know its a broken resource coming with the wrong Response Code. Nevertheless, I dont want Jmeter to mark this test as failed, since I know the reasons and at this time its normal behaviour. How can I teach JMeter to mark it as successful?

Thank you for your friendly support,

best regards

Comment: The answer to my question is in fact: p_auth CSRF token is only used by "action" requests in liferay, this AS distinguishes between different request types. So the question if p_auth will be used depends on what you want to do. Hence this, in my case it should be enough to simulate a form within JMeter on a logon request.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be manually correlating [JSESSIONID](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-is-jsessionid-in-j2ee-web.html) cookie, [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) will do everything for you automatically.

You should focus on handling this `p_auth` dynamic parameter, my expectation is that you're testing an application deployed onto [Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/) application server therefore you should correlate [`p_auth` token](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token) which is some form of [CSRF-protection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) in order to proceed.

Check out [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more information on the concept.

Comment: Dmitri, thank you very much for your friendly assistance. I do understand your point and I have a rough idea what CSRF is for. From comparable examples I have seen within JMeter tutorials its working on same kind like JSESSIONID - unique CSRF tokens are delivered by the server. If Im searching within my project for p_auth, obviously the liferay csrf token, I can only see it in the recorded initial request header (first screenshot), so it doesnt seems to be used in following traffic. Do I miss something? Thank you

Comment: due my last investigation the customer system behaviour is thereby contrary to provided technical documentation from liferay:                                                        
"...Is implemented to prevent Cross Site Request forgery, as explained here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF).

This token is included in every action request in the portal including the "p_auth" parameter in URL..."